# Add field to mongo collection using CLI utility

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a new field to a collection.

I can successfully find the collection:

```
> db.accounts.findOne({ "screen_name": "juancviotti" })
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5169d1c93b95610a4e3bac5b"),       
    "screen_name" : "juancviotti"       
}
```

However I get this non-descriptive error when trying to create the new field:

```
> db.accounts.update({ "screen_name": "juancviotti" }, { $set : { "last_transaction" , 10.0 } })
Sun Apr 14 17:05:51 JS Error: SyntaxError: invalid object initializer (shell):0
```

What syntax error? I'm doing exactly what the docs say.

I'm following this example: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-a-field-in-a-document

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the , with : in the $set (after the $last_transaction)

```
db.accounts.update({ "screen_name": "juancviotti" }, { $set : { "last_transaction" : 10.0 } })
```